# MS Excel shortcut Windows vs. Mac

Tags: macos, keyboard, ms-office

MS Excel for Mac has quite different shortcut keys than Excel for Windows.
Is there any comparison table?

Rather than this 
[http://mac2.microsoft.com/help/office/12/en-us/excel/item/64766a97-9258-4f78-9feb-2742ce769041](https://web.archive.org/web/20121014111103/http://mac2.microsoft.com/help/office/12/en-us/excel/item/64766a97-9258-4f78-9feb-2742ce769041)

I want a table such as

```
Windows  Mac
F4      Ctrl+T   (Cell reference lock)
F2      Ctrl+U   (Cell edit)
```

Comment: // means line break.  I meant to make it look like a table but it won't work.

Comment: Why -1.  Seems like a reasonable question.

Answer (score 2):

There is a side-by-side Excel shortcut guide here: https://exceljet.net/keyboard-shortcuts

It's not in exactly the same format as above, but it's close.

Full disclosure: this is a resource that I created.

Answer (score 1):

I can only recommend to you to download the free Mac app [Cheatsheet](https://itunes.apple.com/app/id529456740?mt=12). It will show you a table with all relevant shortcut keys in any program when holding down the command key for 2 seconds.